# Преобразовать ответ с JSON объектом в DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

Я использую `API` которое возвращает `JSON` объект такого вида:

```
{
"response": {
    "GeoObjectCollection": {
        "featureMember": [
            {
                "GeoObject": {
                    "Point": {
                        "pos": "37.611347 55.760241"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "GeoObject": {
                    "Point": {
                        "pos": "37.593965 55.771575"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Я хочу конвертировать данный объект в `DTO model` в моем `Spring Boot` приложении. Как это можно сделать? Во всех, примерах, которые я находил, рассматривался самый простой объект вида:

```
{
   "foo": 
   [
     {"url":"foo1", "name":"bar1"},
     {"url":"foo2", "name":"bar2"}
   ] 
}
```

И там создали два класса `DTO` и на этом все. Как действовать здесь, не понятно.

Нужно создавать классы `response`, `GeoObjectCollection`, `GeoObject` и т.д. или есть что-то проще и правильней?

**Update:**
Вообщем сделал класс:

```
package ru.geo.converter.model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class GeographicCoordinatesDto {
   @JsonProperty("response")
   private ResponseResult responseResult;
}

@Data
class ResponseResult {
   @JsonProperty("GeoObjectCollection")
   private GeoObjectCollection geoObjectCollection;
}

@Data
class GeoObjectCollection {
  @JsonProperty("featureMember")
  private List<FeatureMember> featureMember;
}

@Data
class FeatureMember {
   @JsonProperty("GeoObject")
   private GeoObject geoObject;
}

@Data
class GeoObject {
   @JsonProperty("Point")
   private PointItem pointItem;
}

@Data class PointItem {
   @JsonProperty("pos")
   private String geoCoordinates;
}
```

Затем пытаюсь маппить:

```
GeographicCoordinatesDto geographicCoordinatesDto = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, GeographicCoordinatesDto.class);
System.out.println(geographicCoordinatesDto.getResponseResult());
```

В итоге возвращается следующее:

```
ResponseResult(geoObjectCollection=GeoObjectCollection(featureMember=[FeatureMember(geoObject=GeoObject(pointItem=PointItem(geoCoordinates=37.611347 55.760241))), FeatureMember(geoObject=GeoObject(pointItem=PointItem(geoCoordinates=37.593965 55.771575)))]))
```

Но, стоит добавить в `JSON` ряд других полей, все падает. Понятно, что данный `JSON` содержит множество других данных, которые мне абсолютно не нужны при парсинге, не описывать же каждый из них в классах. Мне просто нужно забрать координаты.

Неужели ни у кого нет мыслей и с такой задачей не сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не хотите, писать dto объекты, то можно воспользоваться каким нибудь *json парсером*. Например **json**.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.json</groupId>
     <artifactId>json</artifactId>
     <version>2016RE0810</version>
</dependency>
```

Тогда данные, с его помощью, можно получить следующим образом:

```
String text = "{\n" +
            "\"response\": {\n" +
            "    \"GeoObjectCollection\": {\n" +
            "        \"featureMember\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"GeoObject\": {\n" +
            "                    \"Point\": {\n" +
            "                        \"pos\": \"37.611347 55.760241\"\n" +
            "                    }\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"GeoObject\": {\n" +
            "                    \"Point\": {\n" +
            "                        \"pos\": \"37.593965 55.771575\"\n" +
            "                    }\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}";


JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);
System.out.println(jsonObject
            .getJSONObject("response")
            .getJSONObject("GeoObjectCollection")
            .getJSONArray("featureMember")
            .getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("GeoObject")
            .getJSONObject("Point")
            .getString("pos"));
```

> 37.611347 55.760241

Comment: получается, что  "по правильному" нужно описать классы на каждый объект в JSON?

Comment: @RomanAlexsandrovich все очень сильно зависит. Мне лично подход с dto не особо нравится, но иногда его приходится использовать, т.к. он все таки дает какие никакие гарантии на  type-safe +  с ним вроде как понятнее работать.

Answer (score 1):

В Jackson есть аннотация 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties`

У нее есть свойство `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties#ignoreUnknown`
, которое позволяет игнорировать все свойства json`a, которые не объявлены в dto.

Например:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GeographicCoordinatesDto {
```

Только вам необходимо проставить ее и на вложенные классы свойств

Есть возможность объявить такое поведение глобально через конфигурацию `ObjectMapper`:

`objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`